# Namespace issues in XSL to XML generation

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am using SAXON to generate an XML however namepspaces are getting attached the xml generated

```
XSL --> 
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" 
xmlns:ext="http://myorg.com">.........
<ELEM>
     <xsl:value-of select="$application/ELEM" />
 </ELEM>
<LINE_4> ( Using Saxon Extension Function )
   xsl:value-of select="ext:FooFunction("someValue")" />
</LINE_4>
```

Output that's generated is

```
<ELEM xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xmlns:ext="http://myorg.com">NEW JERSEY</ELEM>
<LINE_4 
xmlns="http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/" xmlns:ext="http://myorg.com">12.99%
</LINE_4>
```

I don't want the namespace to be present in the xml generated. Or it should belong to a Default XML namespace which is `http://www.xfa.org/schema/xfa-data/1.0/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want to use `exclude-result-prefixes="ext"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: I generally use exclude-result-prefixes="#all" as boilerplate these days. 9 times out of 10 it gives you what you want.